# design specific button in android xml file

Tags: xml, user-interface, android-xml, android

How can I design some button like below picture in android xml file ?

I dont want to use imageView.I just want to design it with xml.

I use eclipse ide :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/exit_button"
android:text="خروج"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:layout_width="164dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
android:shadowDx="0"
android:shadowDy="0"
android:shadowRadius="5"
/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners android:radius="13dp"/>
<gradient
android:angle="45"
android:centerX="35%"
android:centerColor="#7995A8"
android:startColor="#7995A8"
android:endColor="#7995A8"
android:type="linear"
/>
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp"/>
<size android:width="164dp" android:height="100dp />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain me how can I use this code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    **Define button like this** 
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:text="خروج"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/shutdown"
            android:background="@drawable/square_shadow"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

It's selector like this
```

```
<!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
<item>
    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#2E4D54" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    </shape>
</item>


<!-- White Top color -->
<item android:bottom="13px" android:right="13px"
    >


    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#336E7B" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />


    </shape>

</item>
<item android:bottom="13px" android:right="13px"
    >


    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#336E7B" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />


    </shape>

</item>
```

drawable shut down image [image]

Comment: woow its greate.thanks.but how can I design the right side shadow of the button ?

Comment: please replace selector with updated selector code add android:right="13px"

Answer (score 0):

Everything is done just change drawable top button image according to you and please don't hesitate to ask if you have any doubt.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:text="خروج"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#2E4D54" />
        <corners android:radius="13dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="3dp"  android:bottom="3dp">
        <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#336E7B"/>
        <corners android:radius="13dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```